# why these is a question mark at the end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

i want to get a string like [`www.myweb.com?q=id%3D123456%26action%3Dgo`​]

but actually i get   [`www.myweb.com?q=id%3D123456%26action%3Dgo?`​]

It ends up with a question mark.

My data engine is SQL server 2012

```
declare @id bigint;
set @id=123456;

select 
'www.myweb.com?q=id%3D'+convert(varchar(20),@id) +'%26action%3Dgo​'
```

[image]

Comment: copy and paste above code to notepad.  put cursor between D and g at end near %3Dgo.  now press right arrow key once.  went to between g and o?  right arrow again... o and '... one more time should be to right of ' now right?  but it's not.... right arrow again... now it its... you have a hidden character there that needs to be removed.  Delete and retype the `%3Dgo'`

Comment: your plan works , thanks a lot!

Comment: The `?` appears because it contains a [Zero-Width Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space). While your text editors support the character, the default character collation/encoding in SQL does not. The `?` is the substitute for "invalid" character data. Using natural string literals -- `N'www.myweb...go'` -- will allow SQL to support it.

Comment: Just be sure to accept @sachu response.  he put you on the right track, I just clarified his answer. and Jonathan Lonowski explains why well!

Comment: @xQbert and Jonathan Lonowski well done mates..me too learned something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you check
by pasting the

```
 'www.myweb.com?q=id%3D'+convert(varchar(20),@id) +'%26action%3go​'
```

in sql server query window you can see a non-dsplay character between go and `'` remove that run the query. the question mark will go

[image: result]

Comment: space or a non-display character not sure it's really a space.

Comment: @xQbert ya you are correct some non-display character..not space :),,updated answer

Comment: Even without space am getting `?`. Also there is no space between go and ?

Comment: It's a [U+200B, Zero-Width Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).

Comment: @Fireblade im not getting see my attached pic